# CakePHP Passing Values to Bootstrap 2.x Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a table which contains a button 'Remove'. A modal will appear once the 'Remove' button is clicked. The modal contains a question asking the user if he/she wants to remove the item from the list or not. It also contains another button 'Yes'.

I'm not sure how to pass the data to the modal.

**EDITED**
This is my view:

```
<tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($docs as $docs) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $docs['Upload']['type']; ?></td>   
                    <td class ='actions'>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 pull-right">
                                <?php
                                $uploadDetails = array(
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right',
                                    'role' => 'button',
                                    'tabindex' => '-1',
                                    'id' => 'uploadDetails',
                                    'target' => '_blank'                                                    
                                    );

                                $download = array(
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs pull-right',
                                    'role' => 'button',
                                    'tabindex' => '-1',
                                    'id' => 'downloadButton'
                                    );

                                $remove = array(
                                    'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right',
                                    'role' => 'button',
                                    'tabindex' => '-1',
                                    'id' => 'removeButton'
                                    );
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Html->link('View Details', array('controller' => 'schools', 'action' => 'uploaddetails', $docs['Upload']['iduploads']), $uploadDetails);
                                    ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Remove', '#removeUpload', array('data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-id' => $docs['Upload']['iduploads'], 'role' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right', 'id' => 'removeButton')); ?>

                                    <!--<a href="#removeUpload" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="modal" id="removeButton">Remove</a>-->

                                    <?php
                                    echo $this->Html->link('Download', array('action' => 'sendFile', $docs['Upload']['iduploads']), $download);
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
```

This is my modal contents:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="removeUpload">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                    <h3 class="modal-title">Remove Selected Upload?</h3>

                    <hr>
                </div><!-- end modal-header -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <center>
                        <h4>
                            Are you sure you want to remove the selected upload?    
                        </h4>
                    </center>

                </div><!-- end modal-body -->
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    <br>
                    <hr>                
                    <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" id="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?php
                                echo $this->Html->link('Yes', '#', array('id' => 'delete', 'class' => 'btn btn-success','role' => 'button'));
                                //echo $this->Html->link('Yes', array('controller' => 'schools', 'action' => 'remove', $docs['Upload']['iduploads']), $yes);
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end modal-content -->
        </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- end myModal -->
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#removeUpload').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#delete').attr('href', 'remove/'+$(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
    });

});
```

This is my remove function:

```
public function remove(){
        $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];

        if(!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid action', 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-danger'), 'uploads'); 
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'schools', 'action'=>'documents'));
        } else {
            if($this->Upload->delete($id)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Selected document has been removed.', 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-danger'), 'uploads'); 
            }else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to remove selected document!', 'alert_box', array('class' => 'alert-warning'), 'uploads'); 
            }
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'schools', 'action'=>'documents'));
        }
    }
```

What happens now is that if I hover my mouse to the 'Yes' button I get this message located at the lower left of Chrome: localhost/app/schools/remove/undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to make this work by using this code, and also by using @PawelMysior's answer.

Link of each rows in the table:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', '#modal', array('data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-id' => $field['Model']['id'])); ?>
```

Link in the modal:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', '#', array('id' => 'delete')); ?>
```

And finally, the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a[data-toggle=modal], button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function () {
        var data_id = '';

        if (typeof $(this).data('id') !== 'undefined'){
          data_id = $(this).data('id');
        }

        $('#delete').attr('href', 'link_to_delete_action'+data_id);

    })
});
```

To check if it is working, hover your mouse to the modal link and you will see the path at the lower left side of your browser.

Before when I used @Pawel's jQuery code I see this: localhost/app/schools/remove/undefined

Now, with the updated jQuery I see this: localhost/app/schools/remove/data_id

Answer (score 0):

You have many rows in the table and only one modal. So you're going to have to use javascript to create the delete link in the modal based on which row was clicked.

The link in each row should look something like:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', '#modal', array('data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-id' => $field['Model']['id'])); ?>
```

In the modal create a link:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', '#', array('id' => 'delete')); ?>
```

Add js code (I am assuming you have jQuery):

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $('#delete').attr('href', 'link_to_you_delete_action/'+$(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'link_to_you_delete_action/' mean.